# How to play songs (only songs) from a playlist on iOS?

Tags: ios5, mpmediaitem, mpmediaquery, mpmediaitemcollection

I'm trying to play songs from an iPod playlist. As far as playlist may have videos too, I want to play only songs in them.

```
    MPMusicPlayerController *mp = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];

    MPMediaQuery *query = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];

    query.groupingType = MPMediaGroupingPlaylist;

    NSArray *playlists = [query collections];

    BOOL found = NO;

    for(MPMediaPlaylist *playlist in playlists)
    {
        NSString *name = [playlist valueForProperty:MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName];
        if([name caseInsensitiveCompare:@"MyPlaylist"] == NSOrderedSame && [playlist count] > 0)
        {
            MPMediaItemCollection *collection = [MPMediaItemCollection collectionWithItems:playlist.items];
            [mp setQueueWithItemCollection:collection];
            found = YES;
            NSLog(@"items count %d", [playlist count]);
            for (MPMediaItem *item in [collection items]){
                NSLog(@"%@", [item valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType]);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

After I load a playlist with 1 song a 2 videos, the output is:

**items count 3**
**256**
**256**
**1**

I don't understand why I'm getting videos too, if the query is intended to retrieve songs, and media items have media type MPMediaTypeMovie (256 or 1 << 8).

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One possible workaround would be to create a custom query using predicates. This can be implemented by using the `MPMediaQuery` `items` array rather than the `collections` array. The `collections` array is an array of `MPMediaItemCollection`s. The `items` array is an array of `MPMediaItem`s, so you can filter the query by `MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType`. `MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType` is only applicable to a `MPMediaItem` and not a `MPMediaItemCollection`.

Initialize the query with a set of predicates based on the playlist title and media type. This will select your playlist and filter out any videos from the query:

```c
NSString *playlistName = @"MyPlaylist";
MPMediaPropertyPredicate *playlistPredicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:playlistName
                                                                               forProperty:MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName];

NSNumber *mediaTypeNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:MPMediaTypeMusic]; // == 1
MPMediaPropertyPredicate *mediaTypePredicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:mediaTypeNumber
                                                                                forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType];

NSSet *predicateSet = [NSSet setWithObjects:playlistPredicate, mediaTypePredicate, nil];
MPMediaQuery *mediaTypeQuery = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] initWithFilterPredicates:predicateSet];
[mediaTypeQuery setGroupingType:MPMediaGroupingPlaylist];
```

These `MPMediaPropertyPredicate`s will NOT filter if you return your array from the `MPMediaQuery` `collections` array. You should see media item types other than 1 in the log statements:

```c
NSArray *playlistCollections = [mediaTypeQuery collections];

[playlistCollections enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(MPMediaPlaylist *playlist, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog (@"Playlist title: %@", [playlist valueForProperty:MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName]);
    NSArray *songs = [playlist items];
    [songs enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(MPMediaItem *song, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSString *songTitle = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
        NSInteger mediaValue = [[song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType] integerValue];
        if (mediaValue != 1) 
            NSLog(@"title: %@ - media type value: %d", songTitle, mediaValue);
    }]; // Should return other media types here.
}];
```

The `MPMediaPropertyPredicate`s WILL filter if you return your array from `MPMediaQuery` `items`:

```c
NSArray *playlistItems = [mediaTypeQuery items];

[playlistItems enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(MPMediaItem *song, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSString *songTitle = [song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    NSInteger mediaValue = [[song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType] integerValue];
    if (mediaValue != 1) 
        NSLog(@"title: %@ - media type value: %d", songTitle, mediaValue);
}]; // Should return nothing here.
```

You could also apply a media type filter to your entire library by using only the mediaTypePredicate on the `songsQuery`:

```c
MPMediaQuery *query = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
[query setGroupingType:MPMediaGroupingPlaylist];
[mediaTypeQuery addFilterPredicate:mediaTypePredicate];
NSArray *playlists = [query items];
```